# How to add js code in the head using a function? For a single page

Tags: 7

How can I add a js code in the `<head>` **for a single page** using a function?

I found this module https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector but it seems overkilling just for this.

Answer (score 1):

Please consult [function drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)

> **$options:** (optional) A string defining the type of JavaScript that is being added in the $data parameter
>   ('file'/'setting'/'inline'/'external'), or an associative array.
>   JavaScript settings should always pass the string 'setting' only.
>   Other types can have the following elements in the array:
>
> **type:** The type of JavaScript that is to be added to the page. Allowed values are 'file', 'inline', 'external' or 'setting'. Defaults
>   to 'file'.
>   **scope:** The location in which you want to place the script. Possible values are 'header' or 'footer'. If your theme implements
>   different regions, you can also use these. Defaults to 'header'.

Note scope option in the text above.

Consult this post: [Load JS & CSS Files on Specific Pages in Drupal 7](https://benmarshall.me/load-js-css-specific-page-drupal-7/) for direction on using a template preprocess function wherein to add the js.